# How to debug illegal hardware instruction error in unsafe block?

Tags: rust

Here is the code:

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    data: Option<T>,
    level: usize,
    forward: [Option<*mut Node<T>>; MAX_HEIGHT],
}
```

And I want to iterate the linked list:

```
// let next = some_node.forward[n];
unsafe {
    loop {
        match next {
            None => { break; }
            Some(v) => {
                write!(f, "{:?}", (*v).data)?;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `unsafe` keyword, I get the `[1] 74042 illegal hardware instruction  cargo run` error, so is there anyway to debug this `unsafe` block?

Comment: there is a lot of way of "debuging", this is too broad, this error mean you probably mess a lot with memory, you didn't provide an [mcve] so I will vote to close your question.

Comment: Probably dup/related: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: If your `Node` derives from `Debug` (hint: it should), you could try printing `next` with the new `dbg` macro: `match dbg!(next)`: at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: What's this `!v.is_null()` check? You immediately dereference `v` after the `if` check, so surely it's never null, right? If it is never `null`, then consider using [`ptr::NonNull<Node<T>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html) instead of `*mut Node<T>`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for your comment, and in fact, I will try to use `NonNull` after I implement the basic logic, and also I removed the `if` check, it still crashes.

Answer (score 2):

`unsafe` is a way of saying, "shut up, rustc, I know what I'm doing." In this case, you're assuring the compiler that `v` is always a valid aligned pointer to a `Node<T>`, that the array indexing of `forward` resolves to an array of `Option<*mut Node<T>>` with size `MAX_HEIGHT`.  If any of these assumptions are violated, you're back in undefined behavior land.

You've turned off all the safeties and aimed your compiler at unknown pointers. The rational part of my brain wants to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.

The best advice I can offer with the information provided is to use `rust-gdb` and step through your program until your pointers don't look sane.